# Apex toolkit Envelope change sender, subject and message in Docusign Envelope

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I have two problems with Docusign, first, always it sent the envelope with the same account, no matter who is logged always is sending using the same account, i don't know why.

Second, i want to change the subject and message, i am using the example for apex toolkit and i am using the template, but always it show the same subject Documents for your DocuSign signature.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-sending-template-apex-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

To change the subject of a message you can use the withEmail method and edit the emailSubject property. See the API reference for more details: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/envelope.html

Do your salesforce users have the DocuSign Sender permission? I'm thinking that could be the reason that envelopes aren't being sent from their account.